# When sending firebase data i get Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

i have data received from firebase using snapshot.val() and i am trying to send the data to client with res.json() but i dont know what is happening i get this error when i try to send the data
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

but if I send regular json data {'meow':1} this works

JSON.stringify() doesn't help
this is server code

```
function content(){onValue(ref(config.db, "users/1"), (snapshot) => {
  return (JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()))

})
}

app.get('/m', (req, res) => {
  res.json(content())
})
```

this is client js

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/m').then((response) =>
{return response.json()}).then((response)=>{console.log(response)})
```

Comment: Your content function doesn't actually return anything at all because the database query is asynchronous and its callback is invoked after the function returns.  You can add logging to your code to see how it's actually working.

Comment: @DougStevenson ```console.log(snapshot.val())```  gives this [ { message: 'msg1', time: 1694872529703 } ]
[ { message: 'msg2', time: 1694872532327 } ]
[ { message: 'msg3', time: 1694872548256 } ]

Comment: How about logging the return value of content instead of dumping it directly into express?

Comment: @DougStevenson i am not understanding what you are saying bother writing the code?

Answer (score 0):

Your `return (JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()))` is **inside** the callback for `onValue`. The `onValue` implementation in the Firebase SDK does not expect any return value from the callback, so doesn't do anything with it.

If you want to [read the value from the database once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once), use `get` rather than `onValue`. In addition, you will need to handle the fact that `get()` (like `onValue`) does not return a value **now** as the value won't be available from the cloud until (quite some time) later.

So:

```
function getContent () {
  return get(ref(config.db, "users/1")).then((snapshot) => {
    return (JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));
  });
}

app.get('/m', (req, res) => {
  getContent((content) => {
    res.json(content)
  })
})
```

Comment: i solved the issue by
onValue(ref(config.db, "users/1"), (snapshot) => {
  app.get('/m', (req, res) => {
    res.json(snapshot.val())
  })

})
dont know why this works but it works for now 
anyway thanks